# How do I tee a linux print file

Tags: linux, printing, command-line, tee

How would it tee a linux print file to print to a printer with jet direct but also send a second text file to a windows folder using command line?

Comment: This would probably be better migrated to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by 'windows folder', but this would probably help you:

```
 $ command | tee file | lp
```

to save the output of command in file and send it to the default printer.